# SQL that joins 3 tables and group by ProductId but adds the quantity value

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have data on 3 tables that I need to join for a report that groups product totals for shipping locations.

Tables are:

- `A.` `OrderItem` that contains `ProductId` and `Quantity`
- `B.` `Order` that contains `ShippingLocation`
- `C.` `Product` that contains `ProductName`

This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT B.ShippingLocation, A.ProductId, C.ProductName, A.Quantity
FROM OrderItem A
INNER JOIN Order B ON A.OrderId = B.Id
INNER JOIN Product C ON A.ProductId = C.Id
ORDER BY ShippingLocation
```

My output looks like this:

```
ShippingLocation     ProductId    Name    Quantity
---------------------------------------------------
loc 1                   1          name1      4
loc 1                   1          name1      2
loc 2                   1          name1      6
loc 2                   1          name1      4
```

Would like it to be

```
ShippingLocation     ProductId    Name    Quantity
---------------------------------------------------
loc 1                   1          name1      6
loc 2                   1          name1      10
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum quantity with `SUM` and the `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT B.ShippingLocation
     , A.ProductId
     , C.ProductName
     , SUM(A.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM OrderItem A
JOIN Order B ON A.OrderId = B.Id
JOIN Product C ON A.ProductId = C.Id
GROUP BY B.ShippingLocation
       , A.ProductId
       , C.ProductName
ORDER BY B.ShippingLocation
```